# Extract and replace frames from davinci resolve using python scripting

Tags: davinci-resolve, script

I want to know if there is a way to extract single frames from DaVinci resolve and modify them using a python script or if you can add a hook in fusion so that each frame is run through a python script. I looked through the "API documentation" but can't see any specific way to do this.

This would allow for integration with lots of other tools like OpenCV, TensorFlow and let you do lots of stuff like face detection aruco detection using scripting.

Comment: Not sure about how much access the Fusion/Resolve Python API gives you to internal image data; I.e., not sure if you can “pull a frame” as it sits somewhere in the image pipeline, and manipulate it directly, but you should be able to get clip data, such as in and out timecode, and alter the files on disk (or copies). Haven’t messed around with it too much, but I was able to get fusion to make 3D titles from an RSS feed through a Python module.  Hardest part was getting Resolve to use the right Python. Not quite the same, so still an open question.